# Argument getting triggered even if it is optional and mentioned in getopts

Tags: parameter-passing, zsh, getopts

I have written a script `myscript` which does an action on particular type of files. However there is an option for displaying the filename with -d. If I've not mentioned

```
$ myscript -d
```

also it is saying, invalid file path (because that file should be file_evaluated AFTER the action of my `script` on it) but -d is triggered even if it's not mentioned. How do I solve this? Do help. Thanks.

myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo "Enter source directory: "
read directory
echo
echo "Add a file (with path): "
read file
echo
while getopts ":rd" cal; do
case "$cal" in
r) echo "Renaming..."
echo
;;
d) echo "Displaying the Renamed files.."
echo
;;
*) echo "Invalid option: $OPTARG"
;;
esac
done
shift $((OPTIND -1)) 
echo

find . "*.txt" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
anothescript -r "$file" -d 
done
echo "done..."
```

Comment: Add your script to your question.

Comment: Yeah, I've edited n added it.

Comment: It says /bin/zsh, if that's a typo, update the question as well as the tags

Comment: Wait. I'm sorry but My shell is zsh on my mac and other simple scripts I've written work fine on my mac.

Comment: One minor improvement. Change echo prompt + read to `read "?Enter source directory: " directory` to make zsh automatically display the prompt.

Comment: You also have a bunch of errors - unbalanced quotes, that whole find/while loop at the end doesn't have a variable name for the read, and the find isn't going to do what you want....

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `shellcheck` doesn't have support for `zsh` linting.